# Redirect the console window of an console app to the Visual Studio Output window

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Is there any way of redirecting the console of an Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core Console App to the Output window inside Visual Studio instead of opening an external CMD window?

Best would be a solution not requiring any platform specific stuff, because the application has to be cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

[image: Picture]

*Will only display if running in debug mode.*

Comment: I'm searching for a way to redirect the standard output in such a way as for the Debug output you demonstrated. And to hide the console window while debugging.

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Comment: Well since the package manager console is just that - a console. I changed directories into my app then ran `dotnet run` although for some reason I couldn't stop it even after shutting down VS. You might be able to find a command prompt window extension and run it through that.